# Creating set of folders inside some folders using CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I am planning to create some kind of archive.
Suppose I have these set of folders a = {A, B, C, D}
And I have another collection of folders like b = {1, 2, 3, 4}

Now, how I can create folders using a .bat file such that every folder in "a" has the "b" folders. Meaning that every folder in "a" should have "1, 2, 3, 4" as sub folders.

I tried to do something using xcopy but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me on windows 7:

```
for %%a in (A,B,C,D) do (
    for %%i in (1,2,3,4) do (
       mkdir  %%a\\%%i
    )
)
```

To answer your question about a more general script; put this into a batch file such as `a.bat` and run that.

```
@echo off
rem the directory where I wish to make subdirectories
set mypath=C:\Users\Philip\AppData\Local\Temp\Test

rem go to that directory
cd /d %mypath%

rem the names of subdirectories I want to create for each directory (no outer quotes)
set mydirs=ralph,john,sally,betty,11,22

for /f %%a in ('dir/b/ad') do (
    for %%i in (%mydirs%) do (
        if not exist %%a\\%%i (
            mkdir %%a\\%%i 
        )
    )
)
```

If you want only a subset of directories you can change the outer `for` to use wildcards. E.g. only directories that start with `C`

```
for /f %%a in ('dir/b/ad C*') do (
```

Comment: That worked perfectly fine! Thank You! But I have a further question, is there a way to not specify A, B, C, D? Like using a star (*) ?